# Add span-tags around the text(string), that included in an object

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, word-wrap

Hi I'm trying to change the background color of the text that is included an the object. I'm trying it in vuejs.
I've text(string) and some data(object).
My requirement is, if the word is included in the object. Then I need to change the background color of that particular word.

From the response I'll get the text like this:
`text: "Pavan's\nPavan\nKumar Dasireddy is\ntrying to\nadd\nthe span tag\nto the text\n That is\n in an Object."`.

Calling the `nb2html(this.theText)` function in the `<span id="test" v-html="nb2html(this.text)"> </span>` for replacing the `\n` with `<br>` tag.

After Replacing with `<br>` I can see the UI as below:
[image: picture after replacing with break]

So, when the page loaded the included text should be highlighted with some background color.

> sanbox link: [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/z66jzp0x74)

Eg: In the below code, Kumar is included in the object, so I need to change the background color for Kumar only.

I tried mapping the object and checking the text with `myObject.includes(`${searchText}`)`.
If includes then tried to replace the text with the `<span style="background-color: yellow">${searchText}</span>`.

But span tag not adding to the text.Here is my code sample:

```js
<template>
  <span>
    <el-row type="flex">
      <el-col>
        <el-card>
          <span id="test" v-html="nb2html(this.text)">
          </span>
        </el-card>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
  </span>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'samplefile',
  data() {
    return {
        theText: '',
        text: "Pavan's\nPavan\nKumar Dasireddy is\ntrying to\nadd\nthe span tag\nto the text\n That is\n in an Object.",
        myObject: {
            name: 'Kumar',
            trying: 'add',
            isGood: 'the text which is on tag form of',
            mobile: '9874563210',
            concept: 'trying',
            user:'Pavan',
        }
    };
  },
  watch: {
    document: 'caluclateBoundingBoxes',
    selectedText: 'hideContextMenu',
  },
  mounted() {
    this.caluclateBoundingBoxes();
  },
  methods() {
    nb2html(text) {
        const mainText = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        this.theText = mainText;
        Object.keys(this.myObject).map((key, index) => {
        const searchText = `${this.myObject[key]}`;

        const n = this.theText.includes(`${searchText}`);
        
        console.log(`index:${index}`, `${key}: ${searchText}`, n, 'position:', this.theText.indexOf(`${searchText}`), 'length:', searchText.length);

        const repText = `<span style="background-color: yellow">${searchText}</span>`;

        this.theText = this.theText.replace(/${searchText}/i, repText);
        return this.theText;
        });
        return this.theText;
    },
    caluclateBoundingBoxes() {
        if (this.myObject) {
            this.myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.myObject));
            console.log('the text is:', this.theText);
            console.log(this.myObject);
          }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Please suggest me the possible way to achieve this. Thanks!!

Comment: Since I can't run the snippet, could you add the output of `this.theText` and `this.myObject` to the question?

Comment: @peresleguine,Thanks for the reply,
modified the question. Please check it and let me know if need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `this` as a second argument to `map` should fix this:

```
Object.keys(this.myObject).map((key, index) => {
    ...
}, this)
```

There is a scope issue where the `this` in `map` declaration is not scoped to the Vue component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use vue.js here and perhaps you have different logic, but hopefully this plain javascript snippet could help:

```js
var myText = "Pavan's Pavan Kumar Dasireddy is trying to add the span tag to the text that is in an Object."

var myObject = {
  name: 'Kumar',
  trying: 'add',
  isGood: 'the text which is on tag form of',
  mobile: '9874563210',
  concept: 'trying',
  user:'Pavan'
}

var result = myText.split(' ').map(function(word) {
  if (Object.values(myObject).includes(word)) {
    return '<span class="yellow">' + word + '</span>'
  } else {
    return word
  }
})

var e = document.getElementById('result')
e.innerHTML = result.join(' ')
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

If the above snippet is unavailable check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/peresleguine/pen/QJEbmO).

Comment: @PavankumarDasireddy, sorry, I've not tried Vue yet but I'm sure you can adapt plain javascript for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @peresleguine, for your valuable time and for the code.